# How to find all the children nodes progressively?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a single parent `ID` and I need to find all its children `ID`s and their children `ID`s too and so on.

```
var folder = folderEntity
                 .Queryable()
                 .Where(x => x.ParentfolderID == ID) */value pass in URL/*
                 .ToList();
```

this will get the first set of children only.

how can I go into the depth and get all the children hierarchically?

Comment: Can you provide more info about your class?

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward recursive function like below will do it.

```
public IEnumerable<Folder> GetDescendants(IEnumerable<Folder> list, int parentId)
{
    var result = list.Where(x => x.ParentfolderId == parentId).ToList();
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        result.AddRange(GetDescendants(list, item.Id));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This assumes off course that the graph is non-cyclic.